# Deletion algorithm for a Red Black tree

Tags: red-black-tree

Guys I'm trying to implement deletion algorithm for a Red Black tree and I'm having problem with understanding line three of this algorithm (from a book "Introduction to Algorithms" second edition):

1 if left[z] = nil[T] or right[z] = nil[T]
 2    then y ← z
 3    else y ← TREE-SUCCESSOR(z)
 4 if left[y] ≠ nil[T]
 5    then x ← left[y]
 6    else x ← right[y]
 7 p[x] ← p[y]
 8 if p[y] = nil[T]
 9    then root[T] ← x
10    else if y = left[p[y]]
11            then left[p[y]] ← x
12            else right[p[y]] ← x
13 if y 3≠ z
14    then key[z] ← key[y]
15         copy y's satellite data into z
16 if color[y] = BLACK
17    then RB-DELETE-FIXUP(T, x)
18 return y

First of all there is nowhere in this book explained what the TREE-SUCCESSOR is suppose to look like (no algorithm for that) but I found [this page](http://www.ece.uc.edu/~franco/C321/html/RedBlack/redblack.html): and if I feed this algorithm whit 11,2,1,7,5,8,14,15,4 and then try to delete 7 it finds **predecessor** but if I try to delete 11 it finds **successor**. And that what I can't understand. Why sometimes it takes predecessor and sometimes successor? What criteria are taken into consideration while making this decision? A node's color?
Thank you.

P.S. I also do not quite understand what it's written in line number 13. Does it mean that if y has three colors (neither black nor red) or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tree successor (as the opposite of tree-predecessor [which is in that book i believe]) is generally defined for binary search trees as the node with the next highest key. How it determines it is dependent on the type (red-black in this case) and Im almost positive your book leaves the successor method as an exercise. (i remember the problem :P)

Comment: thanks for your answer but I cannot find nowhere in this book anything about TREE-SUCCESSOR. So why on the web to which I've provided the link sometimes chooses predecessor and sometimes successor? Any reason for that?

Comment: the site you are using makes a note at the very bottom of the page as to why that can happen. It is the way they designed their deletion algorithm. The algorithm from your books looks as though it always chooses the successor. it is a rebalancing issue that as long as it conforms to the rules of red-black can be left to the algorithm designer.

Comment: and yes, this is taken from the website : 
This deletion algorithm may use either a successor or a predecessor. The decision is made as follows: the successor is used if it is red or it is not a black leaf (that is, it could be black with a red leaf); otherwise the predecessor is used. Whether a predecessor or successor is used, either is referred to as the successor in the above description.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're reading CLRS 2nd edition.

TREE-SUCCESSOR is introduced in Chapter 12 section 2 - "12.2 Querying binary search tree". And contrary to what Jesse Naugher says, it's not dependent on the type of binary search trees.

Line 13 you quoted is a typo. It should be "if y !=  z".

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to following code.

http://code.google.com/p/cstl/source/browse/src/c_rb.c

Comment: Is there any example from the 3rd edition instead of the second.  My algorithm cannot tolerate content copying easily, and the 3rd edition of CLRS uses a more attractive algo.